# Unable to run python script, error shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Below is the python script(selenium webdriver) I want to execute. But I see error is being thrown that ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'. I see the module src(folder)  exist. I am trying to execute this in command prompt. Can some one please help me where I'm doing wrong.

```
from src.pages.base_page import BasePage
from src.pages.login_page import LoginPage
import unittest

class Dispatcher(BasePage, unittest.TestCase):

def setup(self):
    super(Dispatcher,self).setup()

def login_eoc(self):
    self.login_page.login()
```

test output:
    C:\NASAuto\tests>py test_dispatcher.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test_dispatcher.py", line 1, in 
    from src.pages.base_page import BasePage
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

run a command line, go to the python folder,

```
python.exe import src
```

and verify if python is able to import src. If not try to reinstall this module

Else

You need to add that directory to the path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../src')
```

Maybe put this into a module if you are using it a lot.

good luck